# creating XSLT from XML to convert into text file

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to XSLT. In one of my task I have to convert XML file into a text file with specific format. I am wondering is there a easy/quick way to get it done.

My XML looks like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<QTKTRes xmlns="http://www.xxx.com/app" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" creationDateTime="2013-03-19T15:40:58-05:00" transLanguage="EN" baseLanguage="EN" messageID="1363722058486545315" appVersion="5 1 20110725-1550" rsStart="0" rsCount="1" rsTotal="1">
<TKTSet>
<TKT>
  <COST>0.0</COST>
  <HRS>0.0</HRS>
  <CHANGEDATE>2013-02-19T14:59:51-05:00</CHANGEDATE>
  <TKTID>101</TKTID>
  <TKTSPEC>
    <ATTRID>PMSCR</ATTRID>
    <REID>101</REID>
    <VALUEN>RDPS</VALUE>
  </TKTSPEC>
  <TKTSPEC>
    <ATTRID>PMSCQ</ATTRID>
    <REID>101</REID>
    <VALUET>RDPQ</VALUE>
  </TKTSPEC>
<TKT>
<TKTSet>
</QTKTRes>
```

`

My Desired Output is needed as below :-

```
COST=0.0&
HRS=0.0&
CHANGEDATE=2013-02-19T14:59:51-05:00&
TKTID=101&
TKTSPEC.1.ATTRID=PMSCR&
TKTSPEC.1.REID=101&
TKTSPEC.1.VALUEN=RDPS&
TKTSPEC.2.ATTRID=PMSCR&
TKTSPEC.2.REID=101&
TKTSPEC.2.VALUET=RDPQ
```

Is there a tool I can make use of or I need to manually write XSLT stylesheet . I am new to this area. Your valuable answers are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to list the child elements of `TKT` with their node name followed by `=`, their value, and `&` on all rows but the last, this should work:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:app="http://www.xxx.com/app">
  <xsl:output method="text" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:template match="app:TKT//*">
    <xsl:param name="prefix" />
    <xsl:param name="inLast" select="true()" />

    <xsl:value-of select="concat($prefix, local-name(), '=', normalize-space())"/>
    <xsl:if test="not($inLast) or position() != last()">
      <xsl:text>&amp;&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="app:TKT//*[*]">
    <xsl:param name="inLast" select="true()" />
    <xsl:variable name="num">
      <xsl:number />
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:apply-templates>
      <xsl:with-param name="prefix" 
                      select="concat(local-name(), '.', $num, '.')" />
      <xsl:with-param name="inLast" 
                      select="$inLast and position() = last()" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your sample input, this produces:

```
COST=0.0&
HRS=0.0&
CHANGEDATE=2013-02-19T14:59:51-05:00&
TKTID=101&
TKTSPEC.1.ATTRID=PMSCR&
TKTSPEC.1.REID=101&
TKTSPEC.1.VALUE=RDPS&
TKTSPEC.2.ATTRID=PMSCQ&
TKTSPEC.2.REID=101&
TKTSPEC.2.VALUE=RDPQ
```

Comment: Thanks again for your respone..
I am trying to alter the XSLT to fit an another scenario.
Consider my input as updated now with TKTSPEC values , I am trying to come up with an output based on your xslt . Is this possible to achieve?